# Count same values from wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My db looks like this:

```
timestamp                user_ip               user_agent
---------                -------               ----------
2015-09-15 01:11:11      111.111.111.111       bla bla Chrome bla bla
2015-09-15 02:22:22      222.222.222.222       bla bla Chrome bla bla
2015-09-15 04:44:44      222.222.222.222       bla bla Chrome bla bla
2015-09-15 05:55:55      222.222.222.222       bla bla Firefox bla bla
```

I need to count the same values of user_ip raw. Timestamp and user_agent are just for records inside db.
Expected result:

```
IP                 Count
---------------    -----
111.111.111.111      1
222.222.222.222      3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Comment: At the moment i'm using just the view, with something like this:
`include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php' ); 
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM my_table" );
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
 ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $print->user_ip;?></td>
    </tr>
 
 <?php }`

Comment: Can you `print_r($result)`?

Comment: Well, the result is something like ip log:
`000.000.000.000 000.000.000.000 000.000.000.000 000.000.000.000 `

Comment: This is wrong ? `Array
(
    [user_ip] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111.111.111.111
            [1] => 222.222.222.222
            [2] => 222.222.222.222
            [3] => 222.222.222.222
        )

)`

Comment: Actually you are right, i didnt use `print_r($result)` because will print timestamp and user_agent too, and i dont need them.
But when i use `$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM my_table" );
foreach ( $result as $print )
{
 echo $print->user_ip;
}` than the ip log will be printed

Comment: Yes but show it to me because i will filter the ip.

Comment: OK, than with `print_r($result)` this is the result:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 2015-09-15 04:43:40 [user_ip] => 104.131.92.125 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 2015-09-15 04:44:05 [user_ip] => 104.131.92.125 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 ) )`
I tried the updated code, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $arr = [
        0 => (object)[
          'timestamp' => '2015-09-15 04:43:40',
          'user_ip' => '104.131.92.125',
          'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 )'
          ],
        1 => (object)[
            'timestamp' => '2015-09-15 04:44:05',
            'user_ip' => '104.131.92.125',
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 )'
      ],
        2 => (object)[
            'timestamp' => '2015-09-15 04:44:05',
            'user_ip' => '102.131.92.125',
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 )'
        ]
];
    $a = json_encode($arr);
    $b = json_decode($a, true);

    $newArr = [];
    foreach($b as $key => $val)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('user_ip', $val)){
            $newArr[] = $val['user_ip'];
        }

    }
     echo '<pre>';
    $arrValues = array_count_values($newArr);
    print_r($arrValues);
```

Here's the result:

```
  Array
  (
    [104.131.92.125] => 2
    [102.131.92.125] => 1
  )
```

Comment: Yup, bingo, it works. Replacing your varibale $arr with `$arr = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM my_table" );` works like a charm.

Thank you very much for your time, buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table GROUP BY user_ip;
```

Comment: Yes that works in mysql. Is there any way to count them in php, like `array_count_values`?